# About app.listen() callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new in javascript and now i'm learn about express.js, but i get some code that makes me confused about how they work. I was tring to figure out how this code work but i still don't get it:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function (){
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

My question is how this anonymous function can using the server variable, when the server variable getting return value from `app.listen()`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The anonymous function is in fact a *callback* which is called after the app initialization. Check [this doc(`app.listen()` is the same as `server.listen()`)](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen):

> This function is asynchronous. The last parameter callback will be added as a listener for the 'listening' event.

So the method `app.listen()` returns an object to `var server` but it doesn't called the callback yet. That is why the `server` variable is available inside the callback, it is created before the callback function is called.

To make things more clear, try this test:

```
console.log("Calling app.listen().");

var server = app.listen(3000, function (){
  console.log("Calling app.listen's callback function.");
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

console.log("app.listen() executed.");
```

You should see these logs in your node's console:

> Calling app.listen().
>
> app.listen() executed.
>
> Calling app.listen's callback function.
>
> Example app listening at...